# lualatex error with Brazilian Portuguese babel option

Tags: errors, luatex, babel

It seems that `lualatex` does not known the Brazilian dialect of the Portuguese language with the [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) package.

When compiling the simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin{document}

Documento de teste.

\end{document}
```

`lualatex` gives the following error message:

```
! LuaTeX error ...re/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:50: luat
ex-hyphen: no entry in language.dat.lua for this language: brazil
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...re/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:22: in function 'err'
    ...re/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua:50: in function 'loadl
anguage'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
\bbl@patterns ...pestring {#1}", \the \language )}
                                                  \fi \fi \fi 
l.165 \ldf@finish\CurrentOption
```

Is this a known bug? Is there any fix for it?

Comment: Interesting. I made an attempt with `\usepackage[portuges,brazilian]{babel}` and `\selectlanguage{brazilian}`, and the error is gone. Just don't ask me why, it was purely trial and error. `:)` I'm also intrigued with this question.

Comment: This does seem to be a bug; there should be a synonym set for `brazil` in the hyphenation pattern database (since there is only on Portuguese hyphenation file). The reason Paulo's solution works is that loading `portuges` is sufficient to load the hyphenation patterns; loading babel with `brazil` as the last language sets it as the main language (so no `\selectlanguage` is needed.)

Comment: The same bug will affect Austrian users, since there's no synonim set for `german` and `ngerman`, while `babel` allows the options `austrian` and `naustrian`.

Answer (score 9):

Khaled Honsy wrote a patch and I submitted a new version of hyph-utf8 to CTAN, so it should end up in TeX Live pretty soon.

If anyone wants to test, try replacing [texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/hyphen.cfg](http://tug.org/svn/texhyphen/trunk/hyph-utf8/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/hyphen.cfg?revision=603&view=co&pathrev=603) and [texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua](http://tug.org/svn/texhyphen/trunk/hyph-utf8/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua?revision=602&view=co&pathrev=602) in your distribution and running

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --byfmt lualatex
```

or simply `fmtutil --byfmt lualatex`. In MikTeX you can rebuild formats somewhere in GUI.

The only language synonyms influenced by the change are currently:

```
canadian               => english   
australian, newzealand => british   
austrian               => german    
naustrian              => ngerman   
brazilian, brazil      => portuguese
```

Claudio Beccari found out that many synonyms fail to work in Polyglossia as well. We might change the way synonyms are treated in future, but this should hopefully get the problem fixed for now.

Comment: `'hungarian'` also needs synonym `'magyar'`.

Answer (score 8):

A quick workaround is to locate `language.dat.lua` on your computer (watch out, there might be two of them, you need the one in TEXMFVAR if you are using TeX Live; mine is at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua`) and change the synonyms for portuguese to

```
synonyms = { 'portuges', 'brazil', 'brazilian' },
```

For a proper fix I'll talk to the author of luatex-specific code for loading hyphenation patterns (Manuel). If he or somebody else can provide a fix quickly, we'll apply it, else I will do a temporary workaround in TeX Live and add the two extra synonyms to `hyphen-portuguese.tlpsrc`. How serious is the issue with Austrian - do people actually use `\usepackage[austrian]{babel}`?

Comment: I guess so: there are notable differences between the `austrian` and `german` options.